# whats the correct way of fix label text in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

This is my code:

```
[_HintLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [lst_word objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord]]];

    [_HintLabel.stringByPaddingToLength:prlt.length withString: @"~" startingAtIndex:0];
```

But the second line of code doesnt work,

How do I fix it so it works?

Comment: For future reference - never use the words "doesn't work". Those are meaningless words. Actually describe the problem. What should it do? What actually happens? If there is an error, include the exact and complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
NSString *newText = [_HintLabel.text stringByPaddingToLength:prlt.length withString: @"~" startingAtIndex:0];
_HintLabel.text = newText;
```

BTW - the 1st line in your question doesn't need the `stringWithFormat:` if the object in the array is already a string. Just do:

```
_HintLabel.text = lst_word[nCurrentWord];
```